# General formula for efficiency of bridge rectifier

Tags: power, converter, efficiency, bridge-rectifier

Is there a general formula for the efficiency of a bridge rectifier ? I have seen a lot of efficiency curve like in the picture attached, but how should I calculate the efficiency of the rectifier based on input or output power alone ? [image]

Comment: Diodes either conduct or block in an ideal sense so, for an ideal bridge rectifier, the power efficiency is 100% - start from that point and add conduction losses and you should be able to figure this out all by yourself.

Comment: Cite link to ref. Diagram, as I have never seen this. The hidden assumptions might be the higher voltage diodes have higher Rs and thus greater losses. In general Rs = 1/2Pmax rated power and from this the voltage drop above 0.6 for silicon or 0.3 for Sch. May be known. Sch diodes have inherently higher Rs so are worse at high power than Si diodes. So a 1W diode will be ~<= 0.25 to 1 Ohm  and a 1/4W PN2222A is 4 Ohms in saturation. A 100W 3V LED will be 0.01 Ohms Rs approx. more or less depending on quality. A 100W 12V LED will be 3x this Rs.

Comment: You pinched that graph from an article about DC/DC converters, not a bridge rectifier https://eepower.com/new-industry-products/300w-phase-shift-full-bridge-dc-dc-with-synchronous-rectification-reference-design/#